# What is the type of an array of function pointers?

Tags: c++, types

I have the following class:

```
class DXStartupEncoder {
public:
   void EncodeA(unsigned char*& message) const;
   void EncodeB(unsigned char*& message) const;
   void EncodeC(unsigned char*& message) const;
   void EncodeD(unsigned char*& message) const;
};

<type> dn_sequence[] = {&DXStartupEncoder::EncodeA, &DXStartupEncoder::EncodeB, &DXStartupEncoder::EncodeC, &DXStartupEncoder::EncodeD };
```

But what is the type of this array of function pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `typedef` if you are not sure.

```
typedef void (DXStartupEncoder::*Encoder)(unsigned char*&) const;
Encoder dn_sequence[] = { .... };
```

In C++11 you could use `decltype` to deduce the type from value, so you don't even need to know how to write the type of a member function  pointer (`auto` can't work, because the right hand side is an initializer_list):

```
decltype(&DXStartupEncoder::EncodeA) dn_sequence[] = { ... };
```

If you need to avoid the `typedef`, by the way, you'll write it as:

```
void (DXStartupEncoder::*dn_sequence[])(unsigned char*&) const = { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have function pointers. You have **pointers-to-member-function**.
2. You're not asking for the type of the array; rather, you're asking for the *underlying type* of the array.
3. The underlying type is:

   ```
   void (DXStartupEncoder::*)(unsigned char * &)
   ```
4. The (incomplete) array type is thus:

   ```
   void (DXStartupEncoder::*[])(unsigned char * &)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The type is called a [Pointer-to-member](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the array as:

```
void (DXStartupEncoder::*dn_sequence[])(unsigned char *&) const = {...};
```

This is obvious from declaration-reflects-use; given an index `i`, a `const DXStartupEncoder &` reference `enc`, and an `unsigned char *&` reference `c`, you would write:

```
(enc.*dn_sequence[i])(c)
```

yielding a value of type `void`:

```
     (enc             .* dn_sequence[i])(c               )
void (DXStartupEncoder::*dn_sequence[] )(unsigned char *&) const
```